# Typescript: How to type ForwardRefExoticComponent + ComponentType

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to type a Component prop that could accept both:

```js
const MyInput = RN.TextInput
```

As well as something more custom:

```js
const MyInput = React.forwardRef<RN.TextInput, RN.TextInputProps>(textProps: RN.TextInputProps) =>
<RN.View>
  <RN.TextInput {...props} />
</RN.View>
```

So, I tried:

```
const MyComp = (props: {
  MyInput: React.ComponentType<RN.TextInputProps>
}) => ...
```

But when trying to set a ref, I get:

```js
const MyComp = ({ MyInput }) => {
  const ref = React.useRef<InputText>()
  return <MyInput ref={ref}
}

/*
Type '{ ref: RefObject<TextInput>; style: { height: number; fontSize: number; lineHeight: number; }; selectTextOnFocus: true; value: string; onChangeText: (text: string) => void; multiline: true; onKeyPress: (e: NativeSyntheticEvent<...>) => void; onSubmitEditing: () => void; onCancelEditing: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TextInputProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'ref' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TextInputProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)
*/
```

Then I tried:

```
const MyComp = (props: {
  MyInput: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
    RN.TextInputProps & React.RefAttributes<RN.TextInput>
  >
}) => ...
```

But in this case, when trying to pass `RN.TextInput` as prop, I get:

```js
<MyComp MyInput={RN.TextInput} />
/*
Property '$$typeof' is missing in type 'typeof TextInput' but required in type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<TextInputProps & RefAttributes<TextInput>>'.ts(2741)
*/
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-christian-0smb9?file=/src/App.tsx) is a sandbox showing the issue

Comment: Please share reproducable example

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-christian-0smb9?file=/src/App.tsx
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `typeof TextInput` solve the TS error for me

```
const MyComp = (props: {
  MyInput: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
    RN.TextInputProps & React.RefAttributes<RN.TextInput>
  > | typeof TextInput
}) => ...
```

I think you don't even need the exotic type because TextInput itself already is capable of receiving a ref

```
const MyComp = (props: {
  MyInput: typeof TextInput
}) => ...
```

Comment: The ForwardRefExoticComponent is for the custom input. As I said, I need to accept both `TextInput` and a more custom input. But thanks, I didn't think about explicitly accepting the TextInput like you did.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Input` doesn't *need* to be a `ForwardRefExoticComponent`.  It can be a regular component as long as it can take the props `TextInputProps` and a `ref` for a `TextInput`.  You can just use `ComponentType` instead.  This allows for components created by `forwardRef` as well as function components and class components.

```
const MyComp = (props: {
  Input: React.ComponentType<
    TextInputProps & React.RefAttributes<TextInput>
  >;
})
```

Now you can use `Input={MyInput}` or `Input={TextInput}` and both will work.